# Prestashop 1.6 - How to stop sending Payment Processed emails for free orders?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In Prestashop 1.6, when ordering a free product, the client still gets sent a "Payment Processed" email.  I would like to stop this from happening.  Can anyone give me a hint as to where to look or what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Confirmation email is sent in paymentmodule class (funcion validateOrder);